# How to write a full CCS Derivation

Tags: algorithms, proof-package

I'm taking a course in modelling of concurrent systems, and the course uses CCS. I'm trying to write out full derivations for some homework problems, but I'm still relatively new to LaTeX. For a single rule, I have:

```
\newcommand{\infrule}[3]
   {\ensuremath{\mathrm{#1}\; {{\textstyle {#2} }\over {\textstyle {#3}}}}}
```

This works fine for a single step. However, I need to chain the steps with a horizontal line between each step, and the rule to the left vertically aligned with the horizontal bar. Also, sometimes the steps branch into separate rules. In this case, the above rule will have one rule on the left and another rule on the right, and the line will be split. How would I be able to do this? I'm using the `algorithm`, `algpseudocode`, and `mathtools` packages, although I could obviously use whatever other package(s) required. Thanks!

Comment: Maybe you can add an image of a derivation similar to the one you need to produce.

Comment: Have you looked at the LaTeX for Logicians site? It includes coverage of some styles apparently liked by computer scientists (or so it claims), along with the rest. I'm guessing here as I can't think off-hand what 'CCS' might be, so I'm pushing it into another discipline. (Also, CS seems more likely given the packages you say you are using.) But maybe it is logic after all. (GCS I might hazzard a guess at.)

Comment: It looks like you're trying to typeset a derivation tree. Have you tried to look at [ebproof](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/ebproof?lang=en) or [bussproofs](https://www.math.ucsd.edu/~sbuss/ResearchWeb/bussproofs/). I'd be happy to provide an example if you provide an image of what you need / want. PS: [latex for logicians](http://www.logicmatters.net/latex-for-logicians/), as suggested by @cfr, might also come in handy.